# How to identify the trigger for selection finish event of a MultiComboBox?

Tags: sapui5

as the title states, MultiComboBox's selectionFinish-function, can be triggered by two things:

1. [Closing Selection of MultiComboBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRpeh.png)
2. [Removing item without opening MultiComboBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCAKx.png)

**Question**: How to identify, what exactly triggered the selectionFinish-function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UI5 does not support this. It treats them as same.